# Consulta por días

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Alguna sugerencia de como podría meter tres consultas diferentes en una matriz de días para saber que días no hubo movimientos. Ya tengo las tres consultas (tabla; registros, ordenes y cotizaciones) por rango de fecha pero me gustaría unirlas. Hacer algo así, tal cual aparece en la imagen, la cuál me indica que no hubo movimientos el día  13.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consulta 1(ingresos, egresos y socios)

SELECT r.fecregistro,
SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 1,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS ingresos,
SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria <> 8,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS egresos,
SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria = 8,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS socios 
FROM `registros` AS r 
WHERE r.idmovimiento IN (1, 2) AND r.idestado <> 7 GROUP BY r.fecregistro ORDER BY r.fecregistro

Consulta 2(órdenes)

SELECT IF (feciop IS NULL, fecicom, feciop) AS fecorden, SUM(totalorden) AS totalorden 
FROM ordenes
WHERE id_estado <> 7
GROUP BY fecorden 
ORDER BY fecorden

Consulta 3(cotizaciones)

SELECT feccotizacion, SUM(totalcotizacion) 
FROM cotizaciones
WHERE id_estado <> 7
GROUP BY feccotizacion
ORDER BY feccotizacion

Comment: Estoy trabajando en Laravel 5.8. Pongo una hoja porque realmente no encuentro la forma de imprimirlo ya que son tres consultas diferentes. Son tres tablas que no se relacionan entre si. Solo es para saber que movimientos hubieron. Disculpa si no fui muy claro.

Comment: Yo podría hacer tres tablas y me va a mostrar en cada tabla solo los días en los que hubo movimientos pues es lo que trae por consulta. Pero necesito unificarlas. Y así saber en qué días no hicieron movimientos.

Comment: La verdad no obtengo errores aún porque no sé cómo empezar con la vista para tener un array de días que estén dentro del rango.

Comment: Probaste con un join entre las 3?

Comment: Te refieres a hacer una unión por el campo fecha? Porque las tablas no se relacionan entre por medio de ID.

Comment: Se puede hacer un join por campo fecha?

Comment: por supuesto!! se puede joinear por cualquier campo... y por lo que se ve en tu grilla, esa es justamente la relacion para que los registros enten uno al lado del otro no?

Comment: Tendría que probar eso. Y si un día no hay registros de ningún tipo como podría mostrarlo en blanco? Es en realidad lo que mas necesito.

Comment: tenes que armar otra tabla mas con todos los dias que queres mostrar.. sql no crea registros magicamente...

Comment: Exacto vuelvo a la pregunta inicial. Alguna idea para crear esa tabla. (Una matriz de días) Alguna sugerencia.

Comment: Ya hay preguntas al respecto de como hacer eso en el sitio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un truco para crear esa "tabla de días" es hacer que una variable incremental haga JOIN con una tabla con el número suficiente de registros, en tu caso, número de días. El número de días lo puedes calcular desde PHP, de tal manera que inicializas la variable con la fecha inicial (menos 1 dia) y el número de días lo colocas en el `LIMIT`.

Ya con la tabla de fechas puedes hacer `LEFT JOIN` con cada una las consultas que tienes:

```
SELECT fechas.fecha
     , ies.ingresos
     , ies.egresos
     , ies.socios
     , ord.totalorden
     , cot.totalcotizacion
  FROM ( SELECT @fe := @fe+interval 1 day fecha
           FROM cualquierTablaConMuchosRegistros
              , ( SELECT @fe := '2020-03-12'- interval 1 day ) v
           LIMIT 4
       ) fechas
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT r.fecregistro
                     , SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 1,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS ingresos
                     , SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria <> 8,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS egresos
                     , SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria = 8,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS socios 
                FROM registros AS r 
                  WHERE r.idmovimiento IN (1, 2) 
                    AND r.idestado <> 7 
                GROUP BY r.fecregistro
              ) ies
       ON ies.fecregistro = fechas.fecha
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT IF(feciop IS NULL, fecicom, feciop) AS fecorden
                     , SUM(totalorden) AS totalorden 
                  FROM ordenes 
                  WHERE id_estado <> 7 
                  GROUP BY fecorden 
              ) ord
      ON ord.fecorden = fechas.fecha
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT feccotizacion
                     , SUM(totalcotizacion) totalcotizacion
                  FROM cotizaciones 
                  WHERE id_estado <> 7 
                  GROUP BY feccotizacion
              ) cot
     ON cot.feccotizacion = fechas.fecha         
  ORDER BY fechas.fecha
```

Comment: Amigo me funcionó perfecto. Usted es un maestro! Mil gracias.